# Cannot load System.Web.Mvc on TeamCity when running MSTest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, teamcity, mstest, visual-studio-2017

I'm converting a working Visual Studio 2015 build on TeamCity to Visual Studio 2017, and I'm having an issue when running MSTest. I'm getting the following error message:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I searched the entire solution and couldn't find anything explicitly referencing System.Web.Mvc v3.0.0.1. I attempted to add the following assembly redirect in the app.config of the Test project to fix the problem:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

However, the problem still persists. After debugging, I discovered the error only occurs in code using System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper. When I comment that code the build works correctly.

The code compiles and tests run correctly when running locally from Visual Studio.

Here's a screenshot of the solution build step in TeamCity:
[image]

And a screenshot of the MSTest build step in TeamCity:
[image]